# Want to add new column in Pandas based on continents

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I basically have a dataframe in pandas with a list of countries, but I want to classify each country by continent, and then by region. I want to add two more columns to the original dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as psql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
suicide_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\slaye\Downloads\suicide_rates\master.csv")
display(suicide_df)

    country year    sex age suicides_no population  suicides/100k pop   country-year    HDI for year    gdp_for_year ($)    gdp_per_capita ($)  generation
0   Albania 1987    male    15-24 years 21  312900  6.71    Albania1987 NaN 2,156,624,900   796 Generation X
1   Albania 1987    male    35-54 years 16  308000  5.19    Albania1987 NaN 2,156,624,900   796 Silent
2   Albania 1987    female  15-24 years 14  289700  4.83    Albania1987 NaN 2,156,624,900   796 Generation X
3   Albania 1987    male    75+ years   1   21800   4.59    Albania1987 NaN 2,156,624,900   796 G.I. Generation
4   Albania 1987    male    25-34 years 9   274300  3.28    Albania1987 NaN 2,156,624,900   796 Boomers
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
27815   Uzbekistan  2014    female  35-54 years 107 3620833 2.96    Uzbekistan2014  0.675   63,067,077,179  2309    Generation X
27816   Uzbekistan  2014    female  75+ years   9   348465  2.58    Uzbekistan2014  0.675   63,067,077,179  2309    Silent
27817   Uzbekistan  2014    male    5-14 years  60  2762158 2.17    Uzbekistan2014  0.675   63,067,077,179  2309    Generation Z
27818   Uzbekistan  2014    female  5-14 years  44  2631600 1.67    Uzbekistan2014  0.675   63,067,077,179  2309    Generation Z
27819   Uzbekistan  2014    female  55-74 years 21  1438935 1.46    Uzbekistan2014  0.675   63,067,077,179  2309    Boomers
```

For now I've been manually compiling nested dictionaries, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this.

```
regions = {'Asia': {'Central Asia', 'South Asia', 'East Asia', 'SouthEast Asia', 'West Asia', 'Middle East'},
          'Europe': {'Western Europe', 'Eastern Europe', 'Mediterranean', 'Nordic'},
           'North America': {'United States'}
```

I apologize if this is a sloppy post, I don't know the formatting on stackoverflow.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming problem. If you are trying to add a continent column, and that information is not already in your data, you should be able to find a dataset somewhere else (try [Kaggle Datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets)) containing country-to-continent mapping to merge with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    custom_country_mapping = {
    'Republic of Korea': 'KR',  
    'Saint Vincent and Grenadines': 'VC', 
    
}

def country_to_continent(country_name):
    if country_name in custom_country_mapping:
        country_alpha2 = custom_country_mapping[country_name]
    else:
        try:
            country_alpha2 = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(country_name)
        except ValueError:
            return 'Unknown'

    country_continent_code = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_alpha2)
    country_continent_name = pc.convert_continent_code_to_continent_name(country_continent_code)
    return country_continent_name
```

You can use this code